# Make try function stop after exception / Better way of managing exceptions

Tags: php, function, try-catch

I have to run multiple functions in order to complete my task. The latter functions are obviously dependent on the previous function running correctly. Right now I am doing it like this:

```
try {

    $depot = getdepot($order['zip']);

    try {

        $id = insert($order, $items, $depot['id'], "Placed");
        echo json_encode(array('response'=>'success','message'=>'Order #'.$id.' successfully placed.'));

    } catch (Exception $e) {

        echo json_encode(array('response'=>'danger','message'=>$e->getMessage()));  

    }

} catch (Exception $e) {

    echo json_encode(array('response'=>'danger','message'=>$e->getMessage()));

}
```

This only has two functions and is starting to get confusing. There must be a better way in PHP to do this.

Comment: You don't need to catch every exception in a separate try-catch-block. You can wrap everything into one single try-catch. After an exception occurs, the catch-statement is being executed immediately and the rest within the try-block gets skipped.

Comment: remove the outer try/catch, if `getdepot()` throws, put it in the try